# C# File download with Firefox issue over https

Tags: c#, firefox, https, download

I have a very weird issue with Firefox only (works fine with IE & Chrome) when I try to download a file stored in SQL DB. Issue only comes up when the user tries to save the file on their machine as it cannot recognize the extension of the file. It works fine if the user tries to open it and browser is able to detect if its a word, excel, or pdf file. Here is my code block:

```
Attachments attach = AttachmentsSession[e.Item.ItemIndex] as Attachments;
string extension = attach.Extension;
byte[] bytFile = attach.AttachmentData;
string fileName = attach.Name;

Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;

if (extension == ".doc")
{
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
}

else if (extension == ".docx")
{
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
}

Response.Charset = "";
Response.BinaryWrite(bytFile);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't comment on ProNeticas' post, so:

"application/word" isn't a recognised mime type, least of all for .docx, and I doubt a browser would know what to do with it.

The correct mime type for .docx is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`, and the mime type he already has is correct for .doc

See [Office Mime Types](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php)

Comment: +1 We had this exact issue with firefox and xlsx files.  It boiled down to having to send the correct mime types

Comment: +1 indeed, look at the accepted MIME types here:

http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Response.AddHeader('Content-type', 'application/msword');
Response.AddHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="file.docx"');
```